# How to perform url rewrites for different flask apps on different locations on same nginx server with uwsgi?

Tags: python, regex, nginx, url-rewriting, uwsgi

I am facing the following probelm: 
I have set up nginx to listen to two different upstream app servers running with uwsgi on different ports. The two applications use the same static files but depending on the nginx location the firstapplication or the secondapplication gets loaded:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name localhost;
    charset     utf-8;
    client_max_body_size 75M;

# Proxy connections to the application servers
        # app_servers
        location /firstapplication {


            include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            proxy_pass         http://app_servers_firstapplication/;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

            rewrite /?(?!/firstapplication)/(.+) /firstapplication/$1 last;
        }

        location /secondapplication {

            include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
            proxy_pass         http://secondapplication/;
            proxy_redirect     off;
            proxy_set_header   Host $host;
            proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;

            rewrite /?(?!/secondapplication)/(.+) /secondapplication/$1 last;      
        }
     location ^~ /scripts/  {
            alias /webapps/scripts/;

        }

     location ^~ /css/  {
            alias /webapps/html/css/;
        }
     location ^~ /graphics/  {
            alias /webapps/html/graphics/;

        }    
     location ^~ /fonts/  {
            alias /webapps/html/fonts/;

        }

}
```

When I call mydomain/firstapplication or mydomain/secondapplication the initial page of the corresponding app gets loaded right.

But when the initial page of the app gets loaded and I click on a link in the app it is using the app's urls like /contact instead of /firstapplication/contact and therefore I geht a 404 error for every url I call in the application.

I wanted to solve this problem with location specific rewrites in nginx like this:

```
rewrite /?(?!/firstapplication)/(.+) /firstapplication/$1 last;
```

and

```
rewrite /?(?!/secondapplication)/(.+) /secondapplication/$1 last;
```

I used a negative lookbehind assertion to avoid a circular redirect when I load the page /fistapplication.
This rewrite regex should work I tested it in this online editor: http://regex101.com/r/yH7sP0/1

Unfortunately nginx does not redirect the application urls and they still lead to 404 errors.

**Can I use nginx rewrite module to achieve my goal? Or what other approaches could I use to run two diffrent apps on the same nginx server?**